# Mysqli database connection issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently using `mysqli` to crate a connection to my database.  My host server doesnt support PDO connections so that is why I am using mysqli. When making the connection I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()
```

Is `fetchAll()` not part of mysqli?

**PHP Connect to DB**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
echo ('Success... '); 
}

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `categories`
            WHERE `master` = 0";
    $statement = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $list = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `$mysqli->query($sql)`, this can return a `mysqli_result` object, or the value `false` in case of an error. I think that your query is not successful, and returns the value false, and of course if you ask for `false->fetchAll()` this will give an error message.

So you have to check first, if the query was successful (use the `===` operator and check for `false`), and afterwards you can work with the result of the query.

P.S. That's why i never write functions myself, with mixed typed return values...

Answer (score 1):

No: it's `fetch_all()`, not `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Alright thank you, but now i am getting this error: `Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it is only available with the [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) However the first comment on the mysql fetch all page describes how you can create a function that does the same thing.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Also it's fetch_all not fetchAll

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `fetch_all()`, instead of `fetchAll()`.

```
mysqli_result::fetch_all();
PDO::fetchAll();
```

**[Manual Entry](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**

Comment: Alright thank you, but now i am getting this error: `Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() `